# How to transfer String type to Object type in Scala

Tags: scala

I am writing scala application, and want to utilize my java library. I have java API function that takes inputs as Object; however, the scala application that calling such function has input type as string. my code is as following:

```
val data = Array("foo", "bar")
val dataSource = new MyJavaAPIDataProvider(data)
```

Because I am using MyJavaAPIDataProvider(Object[] data), the scala code keeps telling me type mismatch. How do I change my scala code data array from a string array to Object array? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to cast the array to `Array[Object]`

```
val objs = data.asInstanceOf[Array[Object]]
val dataSource = new MyJavaAPIDataProvider(objs)
```

Edit:
to complete this answer with Seth Tisue's comment, you also can use:

```
val data = Array[AnyRef]("foo", "bar")
```

To avoid having to cast. AnyRef is equivalent to Java's Object.

Based on that, another possibility that comes to my mind is to create an array of AnyRef with the elements of your string array, like this:

```
Array[AnyRef](data: _*)
```

Comment: Depending on the context in your code, you might also write `val data = Array[AnyRef]("foo", "bar")` in the first place, instead of casting after the fact.

Comment: @Ixx and @SethTisue What if I am using 2D `Array[AnyRef](Array[AnyRef]("ab","cd"), Array[AnyRef]("op","mn"))` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @SYZ you have to use correct type parameter: `Array[Array[AnyRef]](Array[AnyRef]("ab","cd"), Array[AnyRef]("op","mn"))`